# Take string from multiple files and copy to new file and print filename into second column in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have multiple files containing this information:

sP12345.txt

```
COMMENT     Method: conceptual translation.
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..3024
                     /organism="H"
                     /isolate="sP12345"
                     /isolation_source="blood"
                     /host="Homo sapiens"
                     /db_xref="taxon:11103"
                     /collection_date="31-Mar-2014"
                     /note="genotype: 3"
```

sP4567.txt

```
COMMENT     Method: conceptual translation.
FEATURES             Location/Qualifiers
     source          1..3024
                     /organism="H"
                     /isolate="sP4567"
                     /isolation_source="blood"
                     /host="Homo sapiens"
                     /db_xref="taxon:11103"
                     /collection_date="31-Mar-2014"
                     /note="genotype: 2"
```

Now I would like to get the `/note="genotype: 3"` and copy only the number that is after `genotype:` copy it to a new textfile and print the filename from which is has been taken as column 2.

Expected Output:

```
3  sP12345
2  sP4567
```

I tried this code: but it only prints the first column and not the filename:

```
awk -F'note="genotype: ' -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==1{++c} NF>1{print $2, c}' *.txt > output_file.txt
```

Comment: Are those the full contents of those files or just a subset?

Comment: @dawg these files are just a subset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use:

```sh
awk '/\/note="genotype: /{gsub(/^.* |"$/, ""); f=FILENAME; sub(/\.[^.]+$/, "", f); print $0 "\t" f}' sP*.txt

3   sP12345
2   sP4567
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'sub(/\/note="genotype:/,""){print $0+0, FILENAME}' sP12345.txt sP4567.txt
3       sP12345.txt
2       sP4567.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
awk '/\/note="genotype:/{split($0,a,": "); print a[2]+0,"\t",FILENAME}' sP*.txt 
3    sP12345.txt
2    sP4567.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, in GNU `awk` please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS='/note="genotype: [0-9]*"' '
RT{
  gsub(/.*: |"$/,"",RT)
  print RT,FILENAME
  nextfile
}
' *.txt
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, passing all `.txt` files to GNU `awk` program here. Then setting `RS`(record separator) as `/note="genotype: [0-9]*"` as per shown samples and requirement. In main program of `awk`, using `gsub`(global substitution) to removing everything till colon followed by space AND `"` at the end of value of RT with NULL. Then printing value of `RT` followed by current file's name. Using `nextfile` will directly take program to next file skipping rest of contents of file, to save sometime for us.